# Raspberry Pi: start pyqt application without LXDE

Tags: pyqt, boot, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I made a fullscreen GUI application using PYQT4. It is the only thing Raspberry Pi is going to be used for. Is there a way of starting it after boot, without starting unnecessary Raspbian GUI? It uses gpio signals and uinput so it should be run as root.

Comment: take a look at this article Running applications on startup http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=142242

Comment: For anyone else, a short article describing getting started with a Rasberry Pi.  http://techcrunch.com/2012/10/21/getting-started-with-the-raspberry-pi-is-not-as-easy-as-pie/